# MS Access 2007 - Print MultiTabbed Report - VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, tabs

I am creating a form in MS Access that exceeds 22 inches in length. This form is extremely long so I am using tabs to spread out the questions. 
I've now copied the form (with the tabs) on to a report in order to filter the data and to print it.

The name of the Tab control on the report is 'TabCtl219' and the report name is 'rpt_ADMIN'. I'd like to write some vba to print page 1, page 2, and page 3. Considering I can manually flip through the pages on the report, i'd like to print each page using vba. Currently, it will only print page 1.

Your thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you may be going about this in a difficult manner. You can put a button on each tab to run a report and use the information on your form in the report. I think there is a better way to approach your problem.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to get rid of the tab control and spread out the ui-elements and information over several pages.

Comment: that looks to be a possible solution. Thanks